# App Engine Datastore join with filter on reference

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, datastore

I'm very new to App Engine Datastore and I could not figure this out.
I have these models:

```
class SomeUser(User):
        name = db.StringProperty()

class Group(db.Model):
        title = db.StringProperty()
        date_started = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class GroupParticipant(db.Model):
        group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group, collection_name = 'participants')
        participant = db.ReferenceProperty(SomeUser)
        is_owner = db.BooleanProperty()
```

How to query the datastore to get a result like this:

```
Group.title, Group_owner, Number of participants/Group
group1,      someuser1,   3
group2,      someuser2,   4
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no joins at all. You have to fetch all data manually. For example you can fetch all records from `GroupParticipant`, and then fetch all `Group` and `SomeUser` in loop (note that fetching by `Key` is very fast)

--

btw, probably it's better to use different data structures, like

```
class SomeUser(User):
        name = db.StringProperty()

class Group(db.Model):
        title = db.StringProperty()
        date_started = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
        owner = db.ReferenceProperty(SomeUser)
        participants = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

at this case you can fetch all required data by just one query

Comment: Caveat: this does not work for Groups bigger than 5000 participants.

Comment: yes, thanks for a note. that the problem, but you can always split it into few blocks

Comment: I read up about the datastore denormalization techniques and I see what you mean. But how do I filter within a ListProperty? Is there a gql or I have to do it in my program? I need to select all groups that a user is in (simple participant or owner)

Comment: it would be `q.filter('participants =', someUserKey)`, where someUserKey is the key of user you're looking for

Comment: It did not work with participants = db.ListProperty(SomeUser). It gave me a "ValueError: Item type SomeUser is not acceptable", so I went for db.ListProperty(db.Key) wich works just fine. Thanks for your help, splix. Reading the docs about the ListProperty left me as clueless as before; maybe you know why, just for curiosity.

Comment: oh, sure, it must be db.Key. I'll fix it